# Tableau Javascript API

Tags: javascript, class, tableau-api

Can you explain the functions below:

1. `viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);`
2. ```
   function listenToMarksSelection() {
    viz.addEventListener(tableau.TableauEventName.MARKS_SELECTION, onMarksSelection);
   }
   ```
3. `function onMarksSelection(marksEvent) {
     return marksEvent.getMarksAsync().then(reportSelectedMarks);
   }`
4. `function reportSelectedMarks(marks) {`

   `var html = "";`

   ```
           for (var markIndex = 0; markIndex < marks.length; markIndex++) {
               var pairs = marks[markIndex].getPairs();
               html += "<b>Mark " + markIndex + ":</b><ul>";

               for (var pairIndex = 0; pairIndex < pairs.length; pairIndex++) {
                   var pair = pairs[pairIndex];
                   html += "<li><b>Field Name:</b> " + pair.fieldName;
                   html += "<br/><b>Value:</b> " + pair.formattedValue + "</li>";
               }


           }


       }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. This function just listen the selected mark
3. This one throw the selection in reportSelectedMarks
4. It take the marks and write it in an HTML file in a '<'li'>'.
   The fieldname would probably be a String and in the value it depend what you are workin with.

So basically these functions would be useful to dynamically print a selected mark on a graph or something like that and print a fielname and a value for that one.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what each function and method does ?